# Ошибка при повторном вызове модального окна Bootstrap Yii2

Tags: jquery, yii2, bootstrap, yii-bootstrap

При повторном вызове модального окна на фреймворке Yii2 в консоль выводится ошибка

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
```

Хотя при первом вызове все работает нормально

Фрагмент генерации самого модального окна:

```
Modal::begin(['header' => 'Заявка на покупку программы']);
echo "<div id='modalContent'></div>";
Modal::end();
```

Фрагмент JS кода, ответственного за вызов окна:

```
$('body').on('click', 'button.btn.btn-success.buy', function (e) {
    $('.modal').modal('show').find('#modalContent').load( $(this).attr('value'));
})
```

*Пояснение: в атрибуте value на кнопке я держу ссылку на нужный контроллер/экшн
*Примечание: при отправке в консоль $('.modal') в первом случае выводится:

```
r.fn.init [div#w0.fade.modal, prevObject: r.fn.init(1)]
```

а во втором случае:

```
jQuery.fn.init [div#w0.fade.modal, prevObject: jQuery.fn.init(1)]
```

Видимо тут и скрывается проблема, но я не могу понять какая именно это проблема

Comment: Для чего открывать модалку именно так? Если попробовать через data-toggle, data-target?

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, у кого случилась такая же ошибка:

Оказалось, компонент ActiveForm подключает jquery и инициализирует его повторно, отсюда и ошибка. Проблема решилась тем, что я переписал всю форму через yii/helpers/Html

Comment: Что значит инициализирует повторно? По умолчанию jQuery подключается через YiiAsset, потому что он у него в зависимостях. А виджет ActiveForm вообще безправный в этом отношении.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, В моем случае, я неправильно отдавал страницу из контроллера. Вместо положенного renderPartial я использовал обычный render, что привело к тому, что Yii заново начинал подключение всех скриптов, в том числе и JQuery